# How to add index to a csv file that doesn't have an index using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In stack, overflow I see a lot of questions about removing index from dataframes made be `to_csv`.
However, what I want to do is add an index to an already made csv file with no index.

[Here is my file:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8lFh.png)

How do we add an index to this csv with pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read csv file as dataframe, pandas will automatically generate index. You don't need to do something else.

So, just read it and write again as below

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("your_file.csv")
df.to_csv("your_file_to_save.csv")
```